# Upload photo on twitPic and facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, twitpic

Hello I am using Twit Pic in my app.I want to upload selected photo to facebook also ..How could I do this.If I upload then how to know user is logged in at fb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a framework such as ShareKit to facilitate sharing the image on facebook.
I don't think there is a way to tell if the user is logged in without requesting permission to access her account, perhaps via the Facebook sdk.

Comment: Hello I tried Sharekit . But it is not sending emails.Any setting  requires for sending mails

Comment: If you just want to send emails, you can use the message kit ui directly; not sure what your issue is without more info than just "not sending emails"

Comment: I have included messagekit framework. And used share kit example.